# <img> with src to external image without extension not rendering in wordpress/firefox

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, firefox

I'm trying to render and html/php/wordpress output with and image call to an external url that has no extension. The image renders fine in Chrome but I can't get it to render in Firefox. I tried searching for a solution here but couldn't find the exact problem I am running into.

```
<img src="http://someurl.com/image/9780307475503">
```

The site where the image was located originally renders fine on their web page in Firefox but if I include it in my html it won't work.

I also tried putting the following in the .htaccess file and that didn't fix the problem.

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some sites disable hotlinking from other sites in their own .htaccess

Comment: A lot of this might depend on the way that someurl.com handles its responses. For instance, when it receives the request, it can see if the request is coming from a browser on another webpage, and some image hosts disable embedded images this way. You can take a look at the actual network request using a browser's developer tools to see what the server is returning in terms of content/headers.

Comment: After further research it looks like it's actually the noscript plugin in firefox that I had installed chat was causing the issue. When I disabled this plugin it worked fine.